# What is the correct TWINE_REPOSITORY_URL for GitLab pipeline upload?

Tags: python, gitlab, cicd, twine

I've been trying to create my very first GitLab pipeline and have read numerous articles and questions on this topic such as:

[Upload to pypi from Gitlab Pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681816/upload-to-pypi-from-gitlab-pipelines)

and

https://medium.com/packagr/integrating-packagr-with-gitlab-ci-f56c1b33e789

but so far I cannot seem to get the correct TWINE_REPOSITORY_URL as my pipeline returns

```
$ twine upload dist/*
Uploading distributions to https://gitlab.com/glicka/merlot/-/packages
Uploading merlot-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
100% ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 5.6/5.6 kB • 00:00 • ?
WARNING  Received "500: Internal Server Error"                                  
         Package upload appears to have failed. Retry 1 of 5.                   
Uploading merlot-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
100% ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 5.6/5.6 kB • 00:00 • ?
WARNING  Received "500: Internal Server Error"                                  
         Package upload appears to have failed. Retry 2 of 5.                   
Uploading merlot-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
100% ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 5.6/5.6 kB • 00:00 • ?
WARNING  Received "500: Internal Server Error"                                  
         Package upload appears to have failed. Retry 3 of 5.                   
Uploading merlot-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
100% ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 5.6/5.6 kB • 00:00 • ?
WARNING  Received "500: Internal Server Error"                                  
         Package upload appears to have failed. Retry 4 of 5.                   
Uploading merlot-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
100% ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 5.6/5.6 kB • 00:00 • ?
WARNING  Received "500: Internal Server Error"                                  
         Package upload appears to have failed. Retry 5 of 5.                   
WARNING  Error during upload. Retry with the --verbose option for more details. 
ERROR    HTTPError: 500 Internal Server Error from                              
         https://gitlab.com/glicka/merlot/-/packages                            
         Internal Server Error                                                  
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like

```
variables:
  TWINE_PASSWORD: "#MerlotCICDPW1"
  TWINE_REPOSITORY_URL: "https://gitlab.com/glicka/merlot/-/packages"
  TWINE_USERNAME: "merlot"

stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build

build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: build
  image: python:3.11-bullseye
  # only:
  #   - tags
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - pip install twine wheel
    - python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
    - twine upload dist/*
    - echo "Compile complete."
```

I can't seem to get the correct ingredients for my pipeline to publish a build successfully. Can you please help guide me?

My project exists here: https://gitlab.com/glicka/merlot/-/tree/glicka-setup-pipeline?ref_type=heads